# Eliminate in an increasing order rows in a data frame

Tags: r

Eliminate in an increasing order rows in a data frame

```
x<-c(4,5,6,23,5,6,7,8,0,3)
y<-c(2,4,5,6,23,5,6,7,8,0)
z<-c(1,2,4,5,6,23,5,6,7,8)

df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

  df
    x  y  z
1   4  2  1
2   5  4  2
3   6  5  4
4  23  6  5
5   5 23  6
6   6  5 23
7   7  6  5
8   8  7  6
9   0  8  7
10  3  0  8
```

I would like to eliminate number `23` in the df from all columns by instructing to sequentially increasingly remove a row per column (not by matching the value `23`, but by its initial x location).

```
df
    x  y  z
1   4  2  1
2   5  4  2
3   6  5  4
4   5  6  5
5   6  5  6
6   7  6  5
7   8  7  6
8   0  8  7
9   3  0  8
```

Thank you

Comment: The question was leading people astray.  I hope that my edit is acceptable.

Comment: That was my fault.  I read through it too fast.

Comment: Haha, great minds think alike I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
  n <- 4
  df1 <- df[-n,]
  df1[] <- unlist(df,use.names=FALSE)[-seq(n, prod(dim(df)), by=nrow(df)+1)]
   df1
   #   x y z
   #1  4 2 1
   #2  5 4 2
   #3  6 5 4
   #5  5 6 5
   #6  6 5 6
   #7  7 6 5
   #8  8 7 6
   #9  0 8 7
   #10 3 0 8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the columns and remove the element from each, then reassemble as a data frame:

```
result <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(df), function(x) df[-(x+3),x]))
names(result) <- names(df)
result
##   x y z
## 1 4 2 1
## 2 5 4 2
## 3 6 5 4
## 4 5 6 5
## 5 6 5 6
## 6 7 6 5
## 7 8 7 6
## 8 0 8 7
## 9 3 0 8
```

`df[-(x+3),x]` is the column with the value removed, by location.  To start with row `N` in column `x` you would use `df[-(x+N-1),x]`.